# may i know what is exactly meant by "retun class object" in java?

Tags: java

I am new to java.While referring a book i went through a following code.At the end of the code it says "return p"which is class object of Product class. here i am not understanding what it exactly "object p" returns here. I tried to print "p" using println() statement but getting error as "unreachable code".
Can anybody help me here to understant this.

Thanks.

```
public class ProductDB {
    public static Product getproduct(String productcode)
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setcode(productcode);
        if(productcode.equalsIgnoreCase("java"))
        {
            p.setdescription("Murach's beginning java");
            p.setprice(49.50);
        }
        else if(productcode.equalsIgnoreCase("jsps"))
        {
            p.setdescription("Murcha's javs servlets and jsp");
            p.setprice(49.50);
        }
        else if(productcode.equalsIgnoreCase("mcb2"))
        {
            p.setdescription("Murcha's mainframe ciobol");
            p.setprice(59.50);
        }
        else
        {
            p.setdescription("unknown");
        }
        return p;

    }
}
```

Comment: print p before `return p`

Comment: May I suggest you to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html ?

Comment: The reason for printing before the return is that the function exists at that point, so code after it is not executed, resulting in dead code.

Comment: try like this 
`System.out.println(p);
 return p;
`

Comment: I tried System.out.println(p); before return statement and the output is "javalearn.Product@42a57993" . Before @ is my packagename.classname . i assume the thing after @ is may be memory location.

Comment: see my answer @ravi if you really want to print it, you should put a getter method for your Product class

Comment: More specifically, on the page that @RC suggested you may want to specifically read up on [Return Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 0):

it returns all the `datafields` of the object that you set in that method it return 
`p.setcode()` `p.setdescription()` `p.setprice()` u can get the datafields value of the return object in other method by `Product a = getproduct("My String");`
then `a.getcode();` `a.getdescription()` `a.getprice()`

to see the value of p at your `getproduct` method u use `System.out.println(p.getcode());` etc

@ravi to be very specific it return the **instance**  or the **object** of `Product` which is `p` also when you use `return` keyword you also should provide the return type at the

method header public **return type>>>>**`Product` getproduct()

Comment: That doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov what do you mean that doesn't answer the question I was teaching him how return object values can be used in other method,also I had added how to print the object `p` values if he doesn't have `.toString()` method on his Product class, also many comments already teach him how to fix his error on statement not reach

Comment: @ravi if this answer your question please accept it as an answer by checking it ,glad I could help if you have any further question feel free to ask

Comment: He did not ask how to extract values from object, or how to print extracted values. He asked what `return p` means, at least as far as his question wording is concerned.

Comment: i am able to print using p.getcode() but my question still remains same. What is meant by return p. in the book he created one more class called ProductAPP and called the static function of ProductDB as    below. Product product =ProductDB.getproduct(productcode);    My question here is instead of creating   one more object called "product" for Product class why can'y we use the object "p" we created. I assume since the Product class and getproduct()are public we can use object "p" in another class.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov see my edited answers if you need further clarification I could always edit it for you

Comment: @ravi you may want to edit your method header of getproduct() method to become non-static because it cannot be use when you have so many objects you can only use it in one object but when you create another it will always return the same delete the `static` on your method header

Answer (score 0):

The return statement for a method is used to satisfy the return *type* of the method, in this case `Product`. Once a return type has been established in the method signature, the method expects something of that type to be returned (unless void). Because the method has a return type of `Product`, you can store the method call inside another variable to use it later on:

```
Product p = getproduct("productcode");
```

As for the unreachable code error, you'll get that 100% of the time if you try to write code after the last possible `return` statement that can be reached. Once the return type is satisfied, all remaining code is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. Normally "return class object of `p`" means return the [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object of `p`. So in your example either `p.getClass()` or `Product.class`.

*it says "return p" which is class object of Product class* In your code, `p` is not that, it's an *instance* of `Product` class.